# Difference in declaration of virtual method

Tags: c++

Can anybody tell me the difference between:

```
void virtual myFunction();
```

and

```
virtual void myFunction();
```

If there is any. VS doesn't give any error feedback.

Comment: Interesting - I've never come across that first notation before.

Comment: Not sure if I have ever seen the first.

Comment: The first one has `virtual` placed after `void` and the second one has it placed before `void`.

Comment: Did you check if there is any different behavior. It seems to me that the two parses will give the same result. Like `int const` and `const int`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious so you're saying that there isn't any practical difference?

Comment: @RuiSilva If I had to venture a guess, I'd say that either (1) this is a VS compiler quirk or (2) this is a perfectly legal variant and these mean the same thing. Curious to see which is the case.

Comment: @ElvisTeixeira to the extent of my experiments, I haven't seen any difference in behavior.

Comment: I am pretty sure the standard doesn't tell about two different effects for these. If the compiler accepts both, it iis probably an implementation detail. There is probably no difference, even though you should use the second by convention with most code.

Comment: This is legal AFAIK: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Specifiers

Comment: Do note that both g++ and clang also compile the first variant.  I think I have seen this before and trying to find a dupe target

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all.